# Running 2 .py scripts in 1 Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

Short version:
working on a little raspberry pi robot project  using tkinter to control it.
The script works but want to be able to  control the body while the head hits a limit switch so I created 2 scripts to run together in a bash shell.
this creates 2 tk windows but can only control the part depending on which window is active
So i thought having the 2 scripts run in 1 tk window would solve this so i followed this answer:
[How to Open Multiple Tkinter windows in one window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585604/how-to-open-multiple-tkinter-windows-in-one-window)

the script runs and I  get the 1 window but only registers keyboard inputs from mycode2.py and nothing from mycode1.py

Not sure if I have done something wrong or if this is possible ?

If anyone could give me any advice I would be much obliged

Thanks

mycode1.py

```
  import time
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import Tkinter as tk
import os
import random 
from Tkinter import*
from headclass import Right

class Left(Frame):
    def _init_(self, parent):
        Frame._init_(self, parent, width=100, height=100)
        self.config(bg='white')

class Body:
        def __init__(self):
        gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
        gpio.setwarnings(False)

        self.y = 0

        self.command = tk.Tk()
        self.command.bind('<KeyPress>', self.key_input)
        self.command.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.key_release)
        self.command.mainloop()

# Define keyboard inputs   

    def key_input(self, event):
        if ord(event.char) == 27:
            gpio.cleanup()
            quit()
        key_press = event.char.lower()

        if self.y == 0:
            if key_press == 'w':
               print 'W'

        else:
           pass

    def key_release(self, event):
        if self.y == 0:
             self.stop_body()
        else:
            pass  




# instantiate a Robot object to start the program
my_robot = Body()


if _name_ == "_main_":
    root = Tk()
    Left(root).pack(side=LEFT)
    Right(root).pack(side=RIGHT)
    root.mainloop()`
```

mycode2.py

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import Tkinter as tk
import os
from Tkinter import *

class Right(Frame):
  def_init_(self, parent):
    Frame._init_(self, parent, width=100, height=100)
    self.config(bg='black')


class Head:
    def __init__(self):
        gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
        gpio.setwarnings(False)


        self.x = 1
        self.y = 0

        self.command = tk.Tk()
        self.command.bind('<KeyPress>', self.key_input)
        self.command.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.key_release)
        self.command.mainloop()

# DEFINE KEY INPUT    

    def key_input(self, event):
        if ord(event.char) == 27:
            gpio.cleanup()
            quit()
        key_press = event.char.lower()

        if self.y == 0:
            if key_press == 'n':
              print 'N'
        else:
           pass

    def key_release(self, event):
        if self.y == 0:
             self.stop_head()
        else:
            pass


# instantiate a Robot object to start the program
my_robot = Head()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi I have shortened the code

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure out a different plan, still got a single script but added to it and is not 100 % but seeing as its a simple robot project I can live with it